# Avalon-ST interface properties of 10G MAC MegaFunction

Tags: intel-fpga

I have an instance of the [10G MAC MegaFunction](http://www.altera.co.uk/literature/ug/10Gbps_MAC.pdf) that contains an Avalon-ST interface. Reading through the [Avalon-ST specification](http://www.altera.co.uk/literature/manual/mnl_avalon_spec.pdf), I see that every Avalon-ST instance has "interface properties" (see table 5-2).

Now the 10G MAC MegaFunction does specify some of the interface properties (see section 7.2.1) but not all of them. I have tried searching the files Quartus II generated for the interface properties to no avail.

Where can I find the Avalon-ST interface properties of the 10G MAC MegaFunctin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SymbolsPerBeat = 8
DataBitsPerSymbol = 8
Error Width:
  TX = 1
  RX = 6

Source: QSYS instantiation GUI, click "Show signals", and deduce according to Avalon-ST specification.